# how to remove whitespace but not utf-8 character in ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode, utf-8, whitespace

I want to prevent users to write an empty comment (whitespaces, `&nbsp;`, etc.). so I apply the following:

```
var.gsub(/^\s+|\s+\z|\s*&nbsp;\s*/.'')
```

However, then a smart user find a hole by using `\302` or `\240` unicode characters so I filtered out these characters too.

Then I ran into problem as I introduced several languages support, then a word like `Déjà vu` becomes an error. because part of the `à` character contains `\240`. is there any way to remove the whitespaces but leave the latin characters untouched?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way around this is to use `iconv` to discard the invalid unicode characters (such as `\230` on its own) before using your regexp to remove the whitespaces:

```
require 'iconv'

var1 = "Déjà vu"
var2 = "\240"

ic = Iconv.new('UTF-8//IGNORE', 'UTF-8')
valid1 = ic.iconv(var1) # => "D\303\251j\303\240 vu" 
valid2 = ic.iconv(var2) # => ""
```

Comment: An obvious benefit of using an already developed library like iconv is that you do not have to discover all the corner cases yourself (not that iconv by definition is perfect, but it is very likely to be better than what anyone is able to put together by their own).